# PHPStorm - автоматический Upload отредактированных файлов на Remote Host

Tags: phpstorm, веб-сервер, jetbrains

В PHPStorm 2017 можно произвести настройки, при которых отредактированные файлы будут автоматически сохраняться при потере фокуса с PHPStorm.

Также есть возможность редактировать файлы на Remote Host, при этом над каждым редактируемым файлом есть панель с кнопками **"Compare"**, **"Upload"**, при этом необходимо каждый отредактированный файл отправлять на Remote Host через нажатие кнопки **"Upload"**.

Можно ли автоматически делать **"Upload"** отредактированных файлов, при потере фокуса с PHPStorm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно.

**Разрешение на автоматическую загрузку файлов**

заходишь в верхнем меню - `Tools -> Deployment -> Automatic Upload (always)`

**Разрешить загрузку внешних файлов**

Еще, для удобства, зайди в `Tools -> Deployment -> Options..` и галочкой отметь `Upload external changes` , чтобы при добавлении в папку файлов (не через программу PHPStorm), программа сама находила те файлы и перекидывала бы на сервак.

**Видео-урок настройки remote host**

[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v222Dtz7jm0)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там же получается нужно выкачивать тогда удаленный проект в локальную директорию (при этом настраивать mapping между remote dir project и local dir project), так же?

Comment: т.е. чтобы работал автоматический Upload, нужно вначале сделать Download редактируемого файла в локальную директорию.

Comment: да, на локальную директорию тоже надо выгрузить копию. без этого никак.

Comment: @Александр по поводу mapping не знаю. сейчас скину полезный линк